# the "dumps" method of itsdangerous throws a TypeError

Tags: python, flask, itsdangerous

I am following the guide of 『Flask Web Development』.
I want to use itsdangerous to generate a token, but some problems occured. Here is my code:

```
def generate_confirmation_token(self, expiration=3600):
    s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expiration)
    return s.dumps({'confirm': self.id})
```

The `self.id` is an int object.

But unfortunately，the "dumps" method throws a TypeError:

```
  File "/Users/zzx/projects/PycharmProjects/wurong/app/models.py", line 76, in generate_confirmation_token
    return s.dumps({'confirm': self.id})
  File "/Users/zzx/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/envs/venv_blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 566, in dumps
    rv = self.make_signer(salt).sign(payload)
  File "/Users/zzx/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/envs/venv_blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 353, in sign
    return value + want_bytes(self.sep) + self.get_signature(value)
  File "/Users/zzx/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/envs/venv_blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 347, in get_signature
    key = self.derive_key()
  File "/Users/zzx/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/envs/venv_blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 333, in derive_key
    return self.digest_method(salt + b'signer' +
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'bytes'
```

I don't know why this problem occurred, I just follow the guide of my book~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second argument to `Serializer` is `salt`, not `expiration`. `expiration` is not an argument to `Serializer` at all, it's an argument to `TimedSerializer.loads` called `max_age`.

If you want a token that expires, use `TimedSerializer` and pass the expiration when you *load* the token, not when you create it.

```
def generate_confirmation(self):
    s = TimedSerializer(current_app.secret_key, 'confirmation')
    return s.dumps(self.id)

def check_confirmation(self, token, max_age=3600):
    s = TimedSerializer(current_app.secret_key, 'confirmation')
    return s.loads(token, max_age=max_age) == self.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but you are importing the **wrong Serializer**. You probably gave auto import and didn't realize it.

```
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
```

**[Note]**: In the latest version of itsdangerous, TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer is no longer available. If you want to continue using it this way you can downgrade

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74057296/12975352